# mysql chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, group-by

alguem poderia me ajudar a montar essa query?

digamos que eu tenha as seguintes tabelas:

```
tabela1: aluno (id, nome, cidade)
1 Pedro
2 Joao
3 Joaquim

tabela2: cidade (id, municipio)
1 Manaus
2 São Paulo
3 Rio de Janeiro

tabela3: cursos (id, nome)
1 Excel
2 Word
3 Power Point

tabela4: aluno_cursos (id_aluno, id_cursos) -> aqui tenho os cursos q um aluno já realizou
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 2
3, 1
3, 3
```

agora vem a questão. Como faço para buscar, através de um group by, o total de alunos que realizou cada curso, apenas no municipio de São Paulo

meu relatório precisa retornar, por exemplo:
os alunos do municipio de são paulo (where municipio = 2) realizaram:
Word: 3
Excel: 2
Power Point: 3

```
seria algo do tipo select SUM(cursos) from aluno where aluno.municipio = 2 group by cursos
```

ainda não compreendi como funciona o sum e o group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja algo assim.

```
select count(ac.id_aluno), ac.id_cusos from aluno_cursos as ac
join aluno as al on (al.id = ac.id_aluno and al.cidade = 2)
group by ac.id_cursos
```